# Permissions ex is not working

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a kit pvp server and my players are not being able to use signs at all!

```
groups:
  Initiate:
    options:
      default: 'true'
      prefix: '&0[&3Initiate&0]&f'
    permissions:
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.eco
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.pay.multiple
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.afk.auto
    - essentials.mail
    - essentials.mail.send
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.spawn
    - essentials.keepxp
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.warp.list
    - essentials.warp.afireandice
    - essentials.warp.forestlyr
    - essentials.warp.mainplains
    - essentials.warp.spawn
    - essentials.signs.use.balance
    - essentials.signs.use.buy
    - essentials.signs.use.disposal
    - essentials.signs.use.free
    - essentials.signs.use.heal
    - essentials.signs.use.info
    - essentials.signs.use.mail
    - essentials.signs.use.repair
    - essentials.signs.use.sell
    - essentials.signs.use.warp
    - kingkits.command.previewkit
    - kingkits.sign.list.use
    - kingkits.sign.kit.use
    - kingkits.compass
    - kingkits.quicksoup
schema-version: 1
users:
  9bb304e6-2ff2-4acc-b073-d899993e157d:
    group: []
    options:
      name: CraigSwords
  7225aabb-6ae9-4081-add2-00dbdd6d114c:
    group: []
    options:
      name: SocialSavior
  b4c5a860-8e01-4306-99c7-3457e935eed3:
    group: []
    options:
      name: mewtwolvex
  7f1e5c73-3fac-4b5e-b7ed-6661740470a7:
    group: []
    options:
      name: Slick10000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: The title reminded of not the things you had in mind, for sure

Answer (score 0):

Your `Initiate` group permissions appear to be correct. Even though this group is configured to be the default group, it is not assigned to your players since you have explicit group definitions for all (i.e. `group: []`). Removing the *empty group* definitions from your players will cause PEX to assign them to your default `Initiate` group.

Comment: I am getting this error as well http://pastebin.com/nVdedReR do you know what this means?

Comment: BTW, my server is running 1.11.2 and pex is 1.11. Is this a problem?

Comment: @SocialSavior It looks as if you dropped the single-quote at the end of your `prefix` definition causing everything else that follow to be treated as part of that string, unless SnakeYAML detected the start of a top-level token.

Comment: @SocialSavior PEX 1.11 is a very old version (around 2011). I'm surprised that it actually runs. You should use version 1.23.4, which is available at [DevBukkit](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/permissionsex/files). This is the last stable release of PEX 1.

Comment: I meant PermissionsEx v1.23.4 for minecraft 1.11. My server is running 1.11.2. Can a problem occur?

Comment: is there supposed to be two single quotes?

Comment: @SocialSavior You need to provide more details in your questions as I can't know what you see or don't see. I am assuming you are talking about the `prefix` entry. Its value should be enclosed in single-quotes. Make sure that they are single quotes and not backticks. If you take the above PEX configuration as shown in your question and just remove the `group: []` lines from all you players, the permissions should be assigned as expected.

Comment: I fixed it! I had to give individual permissions for each kits and warps. I forget the "s" is essentials.warps. node. For the kits I had a plugin which required permissions for each kit. Thanks for you help.